# Partial update of inner struct in mongoDB without affecting the other fields

Tags: mongodb, go

Is there anyway to partially update the inner struct `Address` in MongoDB? I have below structure defined:

```
User {
   username string `json:"username" bson:"username,omitempty"`
   address *Address `json:"address" bson:"address,omitempty"`

}

Address {
    *isPrimary bool
    line_1 string
    line 2 string
    pin int
}
```

Each time I try to partially update the `pin` or `line_1` or `line_2`, it makes the other parameters null.

Comment: First, you **must** export struct fields: start them with capital letter. If you want partial update, use the `,omitempty` bson tag option, and leave other fields zero. If you need more help, show us what you have and where you got stuck. Aim for a [mcve].

Comment: Although to update a specific field, it's easier to construct an update document that contains only that field, and not use the struct for this at all.

Comment: can you provide an example of how you are doing the update? Here is an example of how I've done it before. In my case the model would only have the fields to update. `filter := bson.D{{Key: "_id", Value: object_id}}
 update := bson.D{{Key: "$set", Value: model}}
 coll.UpdateOne(context.TODO(), filter, update)`